# Is there any way to execute docker push command from the dockerfile itself?

Tags: docker, artifactory

I tried running docker push command from the docker file but it throw an error

The command returned a non-zero code: 127

Comment: Running a command in a dockerfile runs that command inside the docker image, creating a new layer. Docker most likely no part of the image that you're running to command in. Why don't you include the dockerfile? Why the java tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No there isn't. Dockerfile is an image build description format, it is not a general purpose scripting language.

Write a wrapper script if you need to do something that requires a scripting language.

Answer (score 2):

No, these are completely different things: a Dockerfile just specifies the image you intend to build; what happens with the image after (e.g. uploading it into a repository) must be handled by something else (e.g. a script).